# How to snap a WPF app to the nearest screen corner by a certain threshold?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, screen

Basically I have a MouseDown event where I move the window. I want to be able to snap my WPF app to the nearest screen corner by a certain threshold (i.e. 20 pixels), not just a screen edge but the nearest corner.

Which events should I use to accomplish this? I saw some articles but they seem overkill that are subclassing the Window class, etc.

I know I will loop through every corner of the screen and every corner of my app window but I am not sure which events I need to use and which property of the WPF Window gives me the exact coordinates of the window extents.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the location of the screen by SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width(x1) and SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height(y1),and you window's size are this.width(x2) and this.Height(y2).So,we get the four location of corners:(0,0),(x1-x2,0),(0,y1-y2),(x1-x2,y1-y2).
Then,we can use the MouseLeftButtonUp and down event of the window,i tried that but only I clicked in the window it worded.Moving the window when clicking the title bar of it can't trigger event.I thick maybe we can Customize the title bar and write the event in it's MouseLeftButtonUp and down.

Comment: thx I am not using the title bar but WorkArea doesn't fully work with 2 screens.

Comment: maybe you can try  System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea